Laravel: Counting Related Models with constraints on the count query
I have standard Post & Comments hasMany relation
class Post extends Model
{
    // @property int $id
    // @property string $title
    // @property string $user_id

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}


class Comment extends Model
{
    // @property int $id
    // @property int $post_id
    // @property int $user_id (author ids + guests ids)
    // @property string $content

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}

Post can have author and guests comments so user_id field in comments table can contain author_id and guest_ids.

I need to get posts list with eager loaded comments count for author and for guests, so my question is:
How can I get the count of author comments (author_comments_count = 2) and the count of guests comments (guests_comments_count = 3) using withCount()
Thank you in advance

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models does show how to implement this exact thing. Specifically the part that has 'comments as pending_comments_count' presumably you can add more aliases of the same relationship there

Unfortunately, my Comment model does not have approved attribute. Comments must be constrained by user_id attribute before counting them. Is it possible without adding extra attributes to Comment model?

approved is just an example in the docs. You'd use e.g. where('content', 'author comment'); to count author comments

@apokryfos - content may not contain author or guest string. So, in my opinion comments can be filtered only by user_id before counting them. Is it possible?

I see. Yes I don't think there's a straight forward way to achieve this using eloquent operations
